# What is the difference between temporary and persistent variables in TestComplete?

Tags: variables, vbscript, testcomplete

What is the difference between temporary and persistent variables in Test Complete?

Comment: You probably want to start by reading the [documentation](http://support.smartbear.com/testcomplete/docs/scripting/specifics/vbscript.html).

Answer (score 1):

According to the [Documentation](http://support.smartbear.com/testcomplete/docs/working-with/managing-projects/common/variables-page.html)

> *The Variables page is divided into two sections, depending on whether a variable value is stored between test runs or not: **Persistent Variables** and **Temporary Variables**.*

So,

- Persistent - Will hold its value between test runs.
- Temporary - Will not hold its value between test runs.

Comment: I would like to add that temporary variables' values are preserved in different projects and test items within a single project suite run. So, you can use these variables to pass information from one project to another of from one test item to another.